# What will better, make own custom AppBar, or to insert 2 appBar Android Material

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design, material-components-android

I need to have 1 appBar in top where will be information, and another below is search.
But Jetpack offer AppBars not very customizable
I dont know what will better to do

```
Scaffold(topBar = {Column{appBar1, appBar2}})
```

or `Scaffold(topBar = {Column{Row{own implementation} Row{own implementation}})`